# Add to Expression.Lambda 2 condition depend on Boolean returning result

Tags: c#, expression

I have function that return boolean:

```
var lambdaFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression, genericType);
```

How can i add cases in the function depend of the bool answer,if  returns false i want to add `log.debug("false")`,
if it returns true add `log.debug("true")`

My full expression tree that build the function is:

```
                //Input parameter
                var genericType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
                Expression value = null;
                //Get Comparison property
                var key = Expression.Property(genericType, rule.ComparisonPredicate);
                Type propertyType = typeof(T).GetProperty(rule.ComparisonPredicate).PropertyType;
                //convert case is it DateTimeOffset property
                if (propertyType == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
                {
                    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propertyType);
                    value = Expression.Constant((DateTimeOffset)converter.ConvertFromString(rule.ComparisonValue));
                }
                else
                {
                    value = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(rule.ComparisonValue, propertyType));
                }
                var binaryExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(rule.ComparisonOperator, key, value);
                var lambdaFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression, genericType);
```

Comment: How do you use `lambdaFunc`?

Comment: I compile lambdaFunc and run it with value by runtime and get the bool result

Comment: Firstly, you write `log.debug("false")` in both cases check the question. Secondly, what is the problem to do this: `if(lambdaFunc.Compile()(arg)){...}` ?

Comment: I can do it, but can i add it before i compile it?

Comment: I combine BinaryExpression with Expression.Or and Expression.AndAlso but before i combine them i want to add logs depend on the result.

Comment: Combine `lambdaFunc` and `log.debug(...)` to a new `ConditionalExpression` using `Expression.IfThenElse`, of course you need to convert `log.debug(...)` to expression before try to use `IfThenElse`.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria thanks